# Speech service claimed Text-to-speech quotas says 200/sec I can't get higher than 20/min - 600 times slower

Tags: .net, azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

Using the Microsoft Speech SDK (Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech) 1.20.0 I am trying to implement the Azure Cognitive Services Text-to-speech as an upgrade from the Microsoft Speech Platform.

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-services-quotas-and-limits#text-to-speech-quotas-and-limits-per-resource) says 200 transactions per second but every time I test it starts rejecting at ~20/minute (600 times slower). This is on a the F0 free tier, although the standard tier also starts at 200/s.

Basic testing by creating a new SpeechSynthesizer then looping calling SpeakSsmlAsync it reliably fails at 20/min. Waiting on each call so should only be one concurrent connection. On the 21st call in a minute the result is Canceled and the error is BadRequest "Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1007. Error details: Throttled due to too many requests USP state: 3. Received audio size: 0 bytes."

Comment: An older version of the documentation (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/e178a673106be649e443ef616e37d113b0398c26/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/speech-services-quotas-and-limits.md) has: REST API limit  F0: 20 requests per minute S0: 25 requests per 5 seconds. Looks like that still stands no idea why they removed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a query on the documentation [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/88266) and it has now been updated to clarify the free (F0) service is limited to **20 per 60 seconds**

Answer (score 0):

As per my research, there is a latest official document from Microsoft on how to [**Lower speech synthesis latency using Speech SDK**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-lower-speech-synthesis-latency?pivots=programming-language-csharp).

> Normally, we measure the latency by first byte latency and finish
> latency.
>
> The first byte latency is much lower than finish latency in most
> cases. The first byte latency is independent from text length, while
> finish latency increases with text length.
>
> Ideally, we want to minimize the user-experienced latency (the latency
> before user hears the sound) to one network route trip time plus the
> first audio chunk latency of the speech synthesis service.

The solution supports C#, C++, Java, Python and Objective-C. I believe by implementing the given suggestions you may get some better results.

Comment: Unfortunately although latency is also a worry the issue is with the requests per minute, even the provided sample programs show the same issue.